# How to decode properly query string which have UTC date format

Tags: c#, servicestack, query-string

I am decoding query string which contains date `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD` (eg `1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00`) in this format.

I have tried following codes to decode,

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(querystring); 

 HttpUtility.UrlDecode(querystring);
```

But this will convert query string like this

> 1997-07-16T19:20:30 01:00

`'+'`(plus) is replacing with `' '`(space).

How to decode it properly. If any other problem please mention.

Comment: It looks like it wasn't encoded properly in the first place. The plus sign is a proxy for a space in URLs. Therefore, if it is to appear in a query string it should appear as `%2B` which will be decoded as an actual `+` sign.

Comment: Above date format is valid, I am inserting data in url query string through browser. Now where is going to encode the data.

Comment: If you manually enter it in to the browser address bar, then you are going to have to replace the `+` with `%2B` in the address bar.

Comment: I got clue from your answer. But there are other characters like ' { ' , ' } ', ' " ', which no need to replace manually.

Comment: What is still the issue? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: As per scenario I am inserting '+' character manually, but Other characters also I am inserting manually and It has no issue while encoding. So why I am getting for '+' only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147435/discussion-between-ravindra-sinare-and-colin-mackay).